# Upgrading to Visual Studio 2013 from Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2005, upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade directly a VS 2005 solution to VS 2013? MSDN mentions VS 2010 and VS 2012 in some articles about upgrading, but it doesn't mention VS 2005.  We don't have at the moment VS 2013 but our client is interested in upgrading the project.

Comment: what do you exactly mean? you want to upgrade your project or just the VS?? if it is just the VS then it is not a problem, as for the project there might be few minor things to change.. i'd suggest taking the project to someone who already owns a copy of VS13 and try the project there and see how it goes, if fine then just upgrade. i was learning .NET05 but was using VS13... it seemed to have not many differences

Comment: I mean to convert an existing solution created with VS 2005 to VS 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; that should work.

However, VS2005 will not be able to open the upgraded project.

Starting with VS2010, older versions of VS can open projects from newer versions; this does not apply to VS2005.